# Multiple migration statements in one migration file

Tags: node.js, error-handling, migration, sails.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to execute multiple migration statements in a single migration file in order to make changes to multiple columns of same table in one go.

I want to know that whether I am doing it in a write way or not or is there a better and *more appropriate way* to do it:

#### Migration Code

```
module.exports = {
    up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize, done) {

        queryInterface.changeColumn('users', 'name', {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            require: true,
            unique: true
        }).success(function() {
            queryInterface.changeColumn('users', 'address', {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
                require: true,
                unique: true
            }).success(function() {
                queryInterface.changeColumn('users', 'city', {
                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                    allowNull: false,
                    require: true,
                    unique: true
                }).success(function() {
                    queryInterface.changeColumn('users', 'state', {
                        type: Sequelize.STRING,
                        allowNull: false,
                        require: true,
                        defaultValue: "ncjnbcb"
                    });
                    done();
                });
            });
        });
    }
};
```

But I face an error which says:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

Since i couldn't find any way of debugging error in migrations, it will be great if someone helps me out in resolving it or if possible, tell about the way as of how can we figure out the errors in a migration.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your TypeError is probably because you're not returning anything. The [docs](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug#migrations) say that each migration function should return a Promise. No mention of a `done` callback.

To that end, try the following:

```
return Promise.all([
  queryInterface.changeColumn..., 
  queryInterface.changeColumn...
]);
```

Comment: helpful feedback please?

Comment: This method isn't quite right. Any failed queries in there will cause migrations to get stuck. See https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/133#issuecomment-236402184

Comment: As mentioned by @KevinCarmody doing multiple transactions in a single file puts you at risk in getting into an unrecoverable state.  Furthermore, using `Promise.all` will run the migrations in parallel.  These days you may be better off using `async` and `await`.

Comment: My answer is significantly outdated at this point. It is correct in the sense that it addresses OP's primary issue, but see the other answers for ways to write a better implementation.

Answer (score 16):

**Using `Promise.all` with transactions (safer migration) :**

```js
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(t => {
      return Promise.all([
        queryInterface.changeColumn('users', 'name', 
          { type: Sequelize.STRING },
          { transaction: t }
        ),
        queryInterface.changeColumn('users', 'address', 
          { type: Sequelize.STRING },
          { transaction: t }
        ),
        queryInterface.changeColumn('users', 'city', 
          { type: Sequelize.STRING },
          { transaction: t }
        )
      ]);
    });
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction((t) => {
      return Promise.all([
        queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'name', { transaction: t }),
        queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'address', { transaction: t }),
        queryInterface.removeColumn('users', 'city', { transaction: t })
      ])
    })
  }
};
```

Using `Promise.all` without transactions would cause issues if some of the queries are rejected. It is safe to use transactions so that all operations would be executed successfully or none of the changes would be made.

Comment: This should be the right answer, with regard to the last sentence

Comment: I tried to use return promise.all, but the job was just hanging there.

Answer (score 13):

```js
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    try {
      await queryInterface.addColumn('User', 'name', {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      });
      await queryInterface.addColumn('User', 'nickname', {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      });
      return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    try {
      await queryInterface.removeColumn('Challenges', 'name');
      await queryInterface.removeColumn('Challenges', 'nickname');
      return Promise.resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

So this is a combination of 2 answers.

@Firmino Changani - Works great but will complete some of the migrations even if some fail

@Aswin Sanakan - Means they all work or none migrate but if the second migration depends on the first it will not work

I was creating a table and adding a special index to that table.  So I ended up combining them and the below works for me:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async t => {
      try {
        await queryInterface.createTable(
          'phonenumbers',
          {
            id: {
              allowNull: false,
              autoIncrement: true,
              primaryKey: true,
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            full_number: {
              type: Sequelize.STRING,
              unique: true
            },
            phone: {
              type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            extension: {
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            },
            country_id: {
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            is_valid_format: {
              type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
            },
            type: {
              type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
            createdAt: {
              allowNull: false,
              type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
            updatedAt: {
              allowNull: false,
              type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
          },
          { transaction: t }
        ),
        await queryInterface.addIndex(
          'phonenumbers',
          ['phone'],
          {
            name: 'constraint-phone-extension',
            where: {extension: null},
            transaction: t
          }
        )
        return Promise.resolve();
      } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.sequelize.transaction(async t => {
      try {
        await queryInterface.dropTable('phonenumbers', { transaction: t }),
        return Promise.resolve();
      } catch (e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
      }
    })
  }
};
```